# Unable to switch to frame which is inside an iframe

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to locate a frame inside an iframe. I have attached the screenshot of the html page.[image: Html screenshot]

I am able to locate iframe 'content' by xpath  `//div[@id='pageContentDiv']//iframe` which I verified in chrome and my code is working.

```
WebElement frame1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pageContentDiv']//iframe"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frame1);
```

but unable to locate the frame 'detailsDisplay'.I tried  `//div[@id='pageContentDiv']//iframe//frame[@name='detailsDisplay']` but unable to locate in chrome. My motive is to locate the 'Part Details' link element inside the 'detailsDisplay' frame. 
Full code.

```
public WebDriver createPart() {

try {

    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("502409373");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Magic14Magic");
    driver.findElement(By.id("submitFrmShared")).click();
    //Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Select dropCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("txtNewLocation")));
    dropCountry.selectByVisibleText("India");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn']/label")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ds-coachmark-close']")).click();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);     
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='icon-button add']/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ENCActions']/a/label")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[starts-with(text(),'Create Part...')]")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);       
    String subWindowHandler = null;     
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("k1");
    }
    System.out.println(driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler).getTitle());

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='Type-Field']//following-sibling::div//div//input"));

    element.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    element.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    element.sendKeys("Subassy");
    Thread.sleep(4000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-value='Subassy']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Description']//parent::td//following-sibling::td//textarea")).sendKeys("Testing");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[text()='BioSc-DS-Chemical']//parent::select")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[text()='BioSc-DS-Chemical']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Done']")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println(driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler).getTitle());

    driver.switchTo().frame("content");

    driver.switchTo().frame("detailsDisplay");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Part Details']")).click();


} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return driver;

}
```

I am adding 2 screenshots. In the first screenshot I am able to locate the iframe 'content'. In the second screenshot, I am unable to locate the 'detailsDisplay' frame (HTML code is not getting highlighted) by xpath `//div[@id='pageContentDiv']//iframe//frame[@name='detailsDisplay']`

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Is there anything issue with the html tag and document tags in the code ?
I am struggling with this issue quite a longtime. Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Share the full code starting from how you switch iframe finishing with how you locate your link element.

Comment: I have added full code.

Comment: @kiran kumar i am facing a similar issue. can you please share how u resolved this issue?

Answer (score 3):

If your code has nested frames, first switch to the parent frame. Then switch from the parent frame to the inner child frame where you want to locate the element.

Once you switched to the child frame, locate the element which you want.

```
//a[text()='Part Details'];
```

Comment: I tried facing unable to locate error.

Comment: Have you tried with this xpath - //a[text()='Part Details']

Comment: **Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='Part Details']"}** error occured

Answer (score 1):

1.Use the following code to switch into the frame:

```
driver.switchTo.frame(content); //now you have switched into the frame
```

2.Then you need to switch into the details display frame using the below code:

```
driver.switchTo.frame(detailsDisplay);
```

3.Then access the part details using the below xpath:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Part Details')]
```

Comment: I tried these beforehand. But nothing is working out. I am able to switch to 'detailsDisplay' frame through code but facing **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@title='Part Details']"}** while trying to locate th element. In chrome I can locate content frame. but unable to locate 'detailsDisplay' frame. Inside detailsDisplay frame html code is included in #document. Maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: Your xpath seems to be attribute based and //a[contains(text(), 'Part Details')] seems to be a text based. please try this xpath and let me know still you are facing issues.

Comment: **Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='Part Details']"}** error occured.

Comment: Give browser.sleep or proper wait commands after switching into the frame and try to execute

Comment: Tried that too. Its failing again. Firstly, I am unable to locate the detailsDisplay frame in chrome by xpath. I think if we can resolve that we can resolve this issue.

Comment: Remove the double quote and try in the detailsDisplay  
frame.driver.switchTo.frame(detailsDisplay);   this will work

Comment: Also remove the quotes in this command also driver.switchTo.frame(content);

Comment: switchto.farme() method takes arguments of type int, string and webelement. here we are passing it as String right. It doesn't workout giving double quotes.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it works for python but that was how I solved this problem in Java:

the switchTo().frame() method returns a WebDriver that is focused on the targeted iframe. We can reach the sub Iframe using this webDriver like :

`WebDriver subDriver = webDriver.switchTo().frame("iFrameName").switchTo().frame("subIFrameName");`